# Changing default_code in Odoo12 sale

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-12

In product.product model there is code and default_code fields, and in product.template model there is default_code field. These fields have been called/used in sale module. The default_code field is also known as Internal Reference of product. This internal reference is shown in Order Lines page in sale quotation like in the given images in row three, inside the bracket.

[image]

What I want is, in the product column I wanted to display internal reference only and in the description option, I wanted to display product name only. I have looked through the source code and had searched in the google too but no clue. How can I achieve like I wanted, any suggestion will be appreciated?

Comment: Hi, You can go to sale/models/sale.py and search onchange( "product" ) and let me see the code please.

Comment: Hello @Karara Mohamed . I didn't find onchange("product") in sale.py, please tell me briefly which code you wanted to see.

Comment: Hi @Bhuwan Khadka, just search this method >>name product_id_change<<. and let me see the code.

Comment: Thank you @Karara for your response but I had managed to change it, with reusing odoo source code and manipulating it through the inheritance.

Comment: you can change in the product name_get and return only name that you want don't need to change in onchange method because product_id id many2one field and it will display name using name_get method. you need to change in name_get method.